# function inside procedure in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql, function, procedure

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test1 //

CREATE PROCEDURE  test1(IN param VARCHAR(50),IN field VARCHAR(50), OUT res VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

    set @table_name=param;
    set @c2=field;
   SET @t1 =CONCAT( 'SELECT MAX(@c2) into @res FROM ', @table_name);

   PREPARE stmt1 FROM @t1;
   EXECUTE stmt1;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
    SET res=@t1;
   END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Call Methods:

```
CALL test1('tblabc','id', @result);
SELECT @result;
```

I have created a procedure in MySQL , but MAX function is not working. Any solution or alternative? It is giving me the column name instead of the max value.

Comment: See [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c1283/2).

Answer (score 0):

You need be able to assign the variable in the statement, but use `:=` rather than `into`.  Also, you can't use table or column names as parameters.  They need to go directly into the string:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test1(
    IN in_param VARCHAR(50),
    IN in_field VARCHAR(50),
    OUT out_res VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
   SET @sql =CONCAT('SELECT @res := MAX(', in_field, ') FROM ', in_param);

   PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
   EXECUTE stmt1;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
   SET out_res = @res;
END;//

DELIMITER ;
```